# Email with PDF attachments larger than 4 MB getting dropped by Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Have replicated this issue multiple times, from multiple email accounts. I have verified the email passes through the anti-spam firewall (Untangle), but Exchange Message Tracking doesn't even have record of the email coming in. Also, I do not see the test sender email address (my gmail) in our Exchange Logs (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpReceive), and we have "Verbose" logging already enabled on the Receive Connectors.

The only way I *have* been able to send in a PDF larger than 4 MB's is as follows:
Linux VM in off-site test lab > SMTP2Go Relay Email service (with test lab IP whitelisted for anonymous authentication) > Our Exchange.

Any and all feedback on this appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Perform packet captures of the SMTP traffic at various locations, particularly between your anti-spam firewall and your Exchange server. My bet is it will be clear what's happening after examining those logs.

Comment: Thanks, what should I use for packet capture, WireShark?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was on our Untangle UTM. Max message size was far too low (1 MB), plus TLS session were not being allowed. 
[image]